# How is my Android phone deciding to switch the splash screen between light or dark themes?

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Here is the code that I have for my application.  It switches correctly between light and dark but how does it do that? In the styles I don't see any mention of splash_screen_night and yet it seems to be getting called.

**splash_activity.cs**

```
namespace Test.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "test", Theme = "@style/LaunchTheme", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
```

**mainThemeStyle.xaml in values folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_background">#000000</color>

    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MainTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="MainTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**styles.xaml in values-night folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_night</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**splash_screen.xaml in drawable folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
                android:tileMode="disabled"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**splash_screen_night.xaml in drawable folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
                android:tileMode="disabled"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**androidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="000401" android:versionName="0.4.2 beta 3" package="com.test.test">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="Test"></application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually theme names we mention in the `manifest`. Look into the manifest file.

There are 2 options, either to add theme in `app` attribute to apply the theme for each screen, or to add the theme to activity for each screen.

Like

```
<manifest ... >
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" ... >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Or

```
<manifest ... >
    <application ... >
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I just added to the question a copy of that file.  I don't see any mention of options in there. Can you have a look at what I just added and advise.  Thanks

Comment: @Alan2 added manifest code seems not correct one. Look for the file where activities has been mentioned. app -> src -> main ->

Comment: Hi, I just added the splash activity file to the question.  Looks like it calls LaunchTheme.  But I have two of those so I am wondering how it decides which to use.  Note that the code does work correctly.  I am just wondering why it works.  Does it somehow know to use the values-night folder when in dark mode or is it another reason why it works.

Comment: @Alan2 what do you mean by "two of those"?